# цикл while - выведите в консоль все четырёхзначные числа

Tags: java, while

Я только начал учить Java, есть задача:

С помощью цикла `while` выведите в консоль все четырёхзначные числа последовательности **1000 1003 1006 1009 1012 1015...**
Заданную переменную `a` используйте в качестве счетчика итераций цикла и текущего значения последовательности для вывода.
Я сделал вот так:

```
int a = 1000;
while (a < 9999) {
    System.out.println(a);
    a += 3;
}
```

На проверку тест отвечает, что есть ошибка.

Comment: Какая ошибка нам нужно догадаться?

Comment: 9999 входит в эту последовательность? Может, 'a <= 9999'?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Очевидно, что не входит :)

Comment: А что за тест? Возможно, если это какой то автоматический тест, то он хочет последовательность в строчку? `System.out.print(a + " ");` ?

Comment: на этом сайте itvdn.com/ru  во вкладке тренажер - но там надо зарегистрироваться заходите в javastarter потом циклические конструкций задача 2

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код:

```
 int a = 1000;
    while (a < 9999) {
        System.out.println(a);
        a += 3;
    }
```

правильный, не должно быть никаких ошибок. Он выводит числа от 1000 до 9997 с шагом 3. Покажите тест, может вы не так тестируете.

Comment: на этом сайте https://itvdn.com/ru

Comment: во вкладке тренажер -но там надо зарегистрироваться  заходите в javastarter  потом циклические конструкций задача 2

Comment: мне такая задача не попалась в циклических конструкциях, но судя по стилю постановки  других задач, если они  пишут что ` выведите в консоль все четырёхзначные числа последовательности 1000 1003 1006 1009 1012 1015` , то выводите их как `System.out.print(a+" ");`, скорее всего проблема в этом. Я сам там на банальный вопрос мучался отвечал, пока не обратил внимание на подобные вещи.

Comment: сделал  System.out.print(a+" ");  но тоже не принимает

Answer (score -1):

Возможно, что тест не предполагает от вас использование цикла `while`. Попробуйте цикл `for`:

```
for(int a = 1000; a < 9999; a += 3) {
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Я решил таким способом, без ошибки.

```
int a = 1000;

while (a <= 10000) {
    System.out.print(a+" ");
    a = a + 3;
}
```